# Allow duplicates with IN operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(A) AS FREQUENCY FROM TABA WHERE ID IN
(
 (SELECT ID FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT ID FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT ID FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
)
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY FREQUENCY
```

With this query I am always getting the FREQUENCY value as 1.

Suppose say the below sub query gives the below result.

```
 (SELECT ID FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT ID FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT ID FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
2
3
4
2
```

Now the full query is giving only the unique records when used with IN.

I want the results to be sorted by FREQUENCY, in this eg frequency of number 3 is two.
How can I do this? I hope I am making sense.

Basically, I have lots of columns in a table and I want to perform search and return the results based on the frequency of the search items.

Comment: Be aware of the behavior of the COUNT function; if any record contains a NULL value in the `A` column, then that record will not be counted by `COUNT(A)`. That might be the behavior that you want, I don't know, but just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of occurrences of each specific value found in the A column, or are you trying to count the number of times that a specific record matches one of the 3 criteria from your unioned select statements?  If the latter, then your frequencies will only be either 0, 1, 2, or 3; is that your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the correct frequency values using the following:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(A) AS FREQUENCY
FROM (
 (SELECT ID, A FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT ID, A FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT ID, A FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
) TABA_UNION
GROUP BY ID
```

If you need to combine this with the other columns of the TABA table, similar to how your original query is written, then you can do this:

```
SELECT TABA.*, ISNULL(TABA_FREQUENCY.FREQUENCY, 0) as FREQUENCY
FROM TABA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(A) AS FREQUENCY
    FROM (
     (SELECT ID, A FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
     UNION ALL
     (SELECT ID, A FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
     UNION ALL
     (SELECT ID, A FROM TABA WHERE XXXXX)
    ) TABA_UNION
    GROUP BY ID
) TABA_FREQUENCY ON
  TABA_FREQUENCY.ID = TABA.ID
```

Left outer join is used instead of inner join in order to include any records in TABA that don't meet any of the criteria specified in the unioned select statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS FREQUENCY 
FROM TABA 
WHERE XXXXX
  OR XXXXX
  OR XXXXX
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: In the OP, if a single record matches all 3 criteria, then the ID of that record will appear 3 times in the resulting union. In this query, that record will only be counted once, even though it matches all 3 criteria.

Comment: Yes, the IDs will show up 3 times.. but that's in the IN clasue... even if you have dupes in the IN clause it doesn't mean your result will be duplicated. those unions in the IN clasue essentially are OR's

Comment: Ok, but this looks like a restatement of the original query, which the OP says is not giving the desired result (although I notice that the OP's query is grouping by A, which doesn't seem correct). If this is just doing the same thing as the original query, then it doesn't really answer the question.